# Reading a file with Polars that has been created as a TAD file and has sep='\t', lineterminator='\r'

Tags: pandas, database, dataframe, python-polars, tsd

I can read a dataframe like this in pandas (it was originally a TAD file):  `pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Database Nencini/estrapola_articoli.csv', sep='\t', lineterminator='\r')`
How can I do it using polars library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the documentation here: [scan_csv](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.scan_csv.html). There are `separator` and `eol_char` arguments that can be used if needed. Equivalent code:

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.scan_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Database Nencini/estrapola_articoli.csv',
                 separator='\t',
                 eol_char='\r',
                 )
```

I'd be tempted to try it without `eol_char` first.

If you want to read the whole file at once into memory (bad idea, your other post said it was huge), you can use `read_csv()` instead.